# Import excel test to HP Quality Center

Tags: excel, hp-quality-center

I want to import test on my excel document to HP Quality Center, in Test Plan part.

I used add-in excel plugin to import test and it worked fine but the "Req coverage" tab in HPQC get not filled.

I want to fill it with a column in my excel called "Link to req".

How can i do that ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Test Case field mapping in QC exporting wizard is pretty much fixed. I don't recall that we had a field for the requirement linkage, but you can double check the list of fields available at the mapping step. if you found such field you only have to type the letter representing the corresponding column in your sheet. otherwise I am afraid that you will have to do the Requirement/Test Case mapping manually one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can import whatever you can do with the excel. For rest of the thing write a simple program in .net to read excel and do operation in HP (i.e. add req-test link). I did this type of work previously when adding attachment was not possible while import.